# Webpack breaking Sign In With Google button?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webpack, google-signin

When I run my site with using the uncompiled `index.js` file the "sign in with google" button works fine. But when I compile it with Webpack and output it to `bundle.js` the "sign in with google" button doesn't trigger the "signIn()" function that I have set.

Here is the sign in button:

```
<div id="google_sign_in" class="">
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="signIn" data-width="220" data-height="50" data-longtitle="true" data-theme="light"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a picture of the Webpack build script I'm using:
[image]

The "signIn()" function is declared in the `index.js` file that I'm running through Webpack.

I am including `bundle.js` on my HTML page and serving it with Express.js.

When clicking on the "sign in with google" button it opens the account menu and lets me select an account and then updates the button's text to "Signed in with Google", but it doesn't call the "signIn()" function that I have set to be called on data-success.

**I believe it is a problem with the button not being able to find the signIn() function, because the `bundle.js` file is being loaded as I've tested it by simply console logging something out on page load.**

Comment: By default webpack bundle does not expose anything. You should configure webpack to produce a library instead: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library Or expose it manually in your code using `window.signIn = signIn;`

Comment: So is it best practice to download a local copy of all of the js files required for my site? For example, would I grab a copy of https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js and bundle it together with webpack? Because currently just including it in my HTML doesn't work. The signIn() function is running now, but it doesn't work because it doesn't seem to have access to the google sign in source

Comment: If you need something exposed - expose it.